# Auto update client with EventSource on new record

Tags: spring, server-sent-events, reactor

I have the following code. The result I want is that when a new record is created, the client is automatically updated with the new information. Instead, the code below only fetches the records from `findAll`. How do I change my code so that the client is automatically updated?

```java
@RestController
public class CommentController
{
//... 

    @GetMapping(path = "/comment/stream", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
    public Flux<Comment> comments()
    {
        return commentRepository.findAll()
                .publishOn(Schedulers.parallel())
                .log()
                .delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(100));
    }
}
```

To save a comment I use (works fine):

```java
    @PostMapping("/comment/save")
    @ResponseBody
    public Mono<Comment> save(@RequestBody Comment comment)
    {
        return this.commentRepository.save(comment);
    }
```

With (works fine):

```
curl -X POST localhost:8080/comment/save -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '{"author":"author","message":"Message","timestamp":"Timestamp"}'
```

The client side javascript (seems to work fine as well):

```js
function loadComments () {

    this.source = null;

    this.start = function () {

        var commentTable = document.getElementById("comments");

        this.source = new EventSource("/comment/stream");

        this.source.addEventListener("message", function (event) {

            // These events are JSON, so parsing and DOM fiddling are needed
            var comment = JSON.parse(event.data);

            var row = commentTable.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].insertRow(0);
            var cell0 = row.insertCell(0);
            var cell1 = row.insertCell(1);
            var cell2 = row.insertCell(2);

            cell0.className = "author-style";
            cell0.innerHTML = comment.author;

            cell1.className = "text";
            cell1.innerHTML = comment.message;

            cell2.className = "date";
            cell2.innerHTML = comment.timestamp;

        });

        this.source.onerror = function () {
            this.close();
        };

    };

    this.stop = function() {
        this.source.close();
    }

}

comment = new loadComments();

/*
 * Register callbacks for starting and stopping the SSE controller.
 */
window.onload = function() {
    comment.start();
};
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    comment.stop();
}
```

To see the full code:
https://github.com/douma/reactor-sse

Answer (score 0):

I have created a solution:

```java
    @GetMapping(path = "/comment/stream", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
    public Flux<Object> comments()
    {
        return Flux.create(fluxSink -> {
            Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
                .map(s -> {
                    this.commentRepository.findByTimestampGreaterThanOrderByTimestampDesc(lastChecked).take(5).doOnEach(new Consumer<Signal<Comment>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void accept(Signal<Comment> commentSignal) {
                            fluxSink.next(commentSignal.get());
                        }
                    }).subscribe();
                    lastChecked = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
                    lastChecked.setTime(lastChecked.getTime() - 5000);
                    return s;
                })
                .subscribe();
        })
        .publishOn(Schedulers.parallel())
        .onBackpressureBuffer();
    }
```